# Binding big arrays in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3 to visualize data bound to maps and I don't know how big lists should be handled.

If I am using data for industries, there are about 20 or so NAICS which is easy.

As an example, I bind the data from a geojson using this code:

```
 var values = feature.properties;              
 var data = [
    {key: "Agric.,forestry., fishing.,hunting.", name:"N11",value:values["N11"]},
    {key: "Mining.,quar., oil,gas", name:"N21",value:values["N21"]},
    {key: "Utilities", name:"N22",value:values["N22"]},
    {key: "Constr.", name:"N23OL",value:values["N23"]},
    {key: "Manuf.", name:"N31_33OL",value:values["N31-33"]},
    {key: "Wholesale trade", name:"N41OL",value:values["N41"]},
    {key: "Retail trade", name:"N44-45",value:values["N44-45"]},
    {key: "Transportation, warehousing", name:"N48-49",value:values["N48-49"]},
    {key: "Information, cultur.industries", name:"N51",value:values["N51"]},
    {key: "Finance, insurance", name:"N52",value:values["N52"]},
    {key: "Real estate, rental,leasing", name:"N53",value:values["N53"]},
    {key: "Prof.scientific, techn.services", name:"N54",value:values["N54"]},
    {key: "Management companies,enterprises", name:"N55",value:values["N55"]},
    {key: "Admin.support, waste.manag., remed.services", name:"N56",value:values["N56"]},
    {key: "Educational services", name:"N61",value:values["N61"]},
    {key: "Health.care, social.assistance", name:"N62",value:values["N62"]},
    {key: "Arts,entertainment, recreation", name:"N71",value:values["N71"]},
    {key: "Accommodation, food.services", name:"N72",value:values["N72"]},
    {key: "Other.services (except.pub. admin.)", name:"N81",value:values["N81"]},
    {key: "Public administration", name:"N91",value:values["N91"]}
];
```

Now if I wanted to use occupations data, it gets tricky because there are around 800 of them. Clearly, typing them by hand like this is not practical. How would that be handled? Import a CSV with d3.csv and join with the geojson data object? I don't know where to start.

Here is an example of what I do with smaller sets: https://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/tr5pxv1s/

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you know exactly what you do, you've just missed the best examples to learn from:

[Example visualisation mapping reasonably large data-set loaded from tab-separated-values](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606).

What's easy to overlook in that example is how it uses `d3.queue()`, `defer()` and `await()` to ensure the data's loaded and processed in the right order.

Also see [documentation for other CSV-related functions](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md).